# Open native ifstream with file descriptor

Tags: c++, ifstream, file-descriptor

I can't find way how to pass file descriptor to ifstream or how to open ifstream with file descriptor. How can I do it?

EDIT: I found [this implementation](http://www.josuttis.com/cppcode/fdstream.html).

But it gives me not the same results like ifstream, can someone help me please?

Here is test code. To prevent issues I test it in private folder, this way I avoid file restrictions:

-----ifstream-----

```
Bit8u buf[2048];
ifstream in("/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/xxxx.xxxx/files/testfile.png");
in.seekg(100, ios::beg);
in.read((char*)buf, 2048);
```

-----fdistream-----

```
Bit8u buf[2048];
int fd = fileno(fopen("/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/xxxx.xxxx/files/testfile.png", "rb"));
fdistream in(fd);
in.seekg(100, ios::beg);
in.read((char*)buf, 2048);
```

Comment: `/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/xxxx.xxxx/files/testfile.png` That is indeed in private memory of your app. You can continue using it. What is the problem exactly?

Comment: I will use it with SAF, I am testing functionality with file descriptor, for result comparison I placed files to private folder and one time I open it with fd stream another time with ifstream. At the end I want use only fd version with saf, file will be in public location

Comment: If you want to describe a problem you will get with Android Q then do not take paths to private memory as they are still readable under Android.Q. You should post code with a path that is not readable under Android.Q. You name Storage Access Framework. But there is nothing of it in your post. Shouldnt you post a path that you got from saf? I think so.

Comment: Thank you I'll update title

Comment: There is not a single file descripter in your post. So how can you ask how to pass it to somewhere?

Comment: You removed the android tag.

Comment: fileno returns files descriptor

Comment: Again: you did not post code. I see no fileno. I see no file descriptor.

Comment: it is in code under -----fdistream-----

Comment: ok .. sorry .. i was blind

Comment: can you help me?

Comment: So what you are trying to tell us but did not is that `ifstream in(fd);` is not possible?

Comment: Yes, ifstream does not support file descriptors, so I can't use it with SAF. I am looking for replacement which can accept file descriptor and open file on protected storage. At beginning I did not know that ifstream does not support it, now I am sure it does not.

Comment: And why dont you want to use fdistream ?

Comment: Sorry I moved to specialized android forum, seems here it leads nowhere